# How to store csv data in a list

Tags: dart

I want to read a csv file and store the content in a list of abjects. So I created the respective object and made an inputstream to read the file. But when I try to acces the list from outside of the function it's empty, so I thing, that the data is stored in a copy of listOfStocks and not directly in the list, like I want. So how can I store the content in the list?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

main(List arguments) {
  final File file = new File("../Data/In.List.toDart.csv");
  Stream<List> inputStream = file.openRead();
  List<Stock> listOfStocks = new List();

  inputStream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(new LineSplitter())
    .listen((String line) {
      List row = line.split(',');
      Stock stock = new Stock();
      stock.setSymbol(row[0]);
      stock.setDesc(row[1]);
      stock.setExchange(row[2]);
      listOfStocks.add(stock);
      print(listOfStocks.length);
    },
    onDone: () { print('All read.'); },
    onError: (e) { print(e.toString()); });

    print(listOfStocks.length);

}

class Stock {
  String symbol;
  String desc;
  String exchange;

  void setSymbol(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
  }

  void setExchange(String exchange) {
    this.exchange = exchange;
  }

  String getSymbol() {
    return symbol;
  }

  String getDesc() {
    return desc;
  }

  String getExchange() {
    return exchange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inputStream` is asynchronous, so it will take some time before the file has been read. 
The `inputStream.transform(...).transform(...).listen(...)` call completes immediately, then the stream will emit events when something has been read from the disk, and the `listOfStocks` will be gradually populated.

If you need the content of the list "immediately", that is: before you do anything else, you will have to *block* until the list is fully populated.

You can do this in two ways:

1. Read the file synchronously. This makes the operating system block until the file has been read completely into memory.

   ```
   var content = file.readAsStringSync(); // Defaults to UTF-8 decoding.
   for (var line in LineSplitter.split(content))
     ...
     lineOfStocks.add(stock);
   }
   print(listOfStocks.length);
   ```
2. Read the file asynchronously, but wait for the transformation to complete:

   ```
   main(List arguments) async {
     ...
     await inputStream
       .transform(utf8.decoder)
       .transform(const LineSplitter())
       .forEach((String line) {   // Use forEach instead of listen
         ...
         listOfStocks.add(stock);
       });
     print(listOfStocks.length); 
   }
   ```

   I you use `forEach` instead of `listen`, it returns a future which completes
   when the stream is done. With `listen`, you get a done event that you have
   to handle manually.